# How to check if a float value is null in C?

Tags: c

I'm using C and OpenGL and I'm having trouble with trying to compare a `GLfloat` type list with `NULL`:

```
int i = 0;
int m = 0;

    void glPolygonMove(GLfloat PolygonCoords[i][m], GLfloat xPosition, GLfloat yPosition)   // function to add x and y to poly pos
{
        for(int i = 0; PolygonCoords[i][m] != NULL && PolygonCoords[i][m + 1] != NULL; i++){
                PolygonCoords[i][m] += xPosition;
                PolygonCoords[i][m + 1] += yPosition;
        }   

}
```

When I compile the code, GCC signals that it can't compare Float's to Null's. Is there any other way that I can compare or know when the value of a `float list[i] == nothing`?

PS: `GLfloat` type is the same as `float`.

Comment: `GlFloat` is basically a `float`, and floats (doubles, etc.) do *not have* `NULL` values.  `NULL` is specifically for pointers, not values of any other type.

Comment: If you want a "null" value for floating-point work, you might be able to use [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Comment: If anything, `NULL` is 0 (although it's not that simple), and you clearly can't use zero as a "nothing" value for floats.

Comment: `float`s cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: If your polygons coords can't have negative values, you can initialize them to -1.0 then check if they're negative instead of equal to NULL (or similarly, if their values are all > -1000, init to -1000.0 etc...)

Comment: @user16217248 If a `float` can be 0, since `NULL` may be an integer with the value of 0, a `float` can be `NULL`.  Yet OP is aiming for something else  - something other than to compare  a `float` with zero.

Comment: @Tylogree, Please post the code that assigned the various `PolygonCoords[i][m]`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing two mistakes here:

- how to check that a floating point value is zero?
- zero does not equal `null`

Let's start with the latter: the term `null` is the "initialisation" value for pointers, which point at nothing. It is not the same as the number value `0` (zero).
Next: it makes no sense checking if a floating point value equals zero, because in most programming languages, `1.0/3*3 - 1` is not equal to zero, but it will be equal to some very small value, depending on the accuracy of the computer. Therefore it is better checking that a value is smaller than a small margin value (like `1E-15` or something).

Comment: `null` is not  defined in C.  C is case sensitive.  OP does not use `null`, but `NULL`.  This answer is mixing the idea of a _null pointer_ and the _null pointer constant_ `NULL` with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point numbers have a special way to encode invalid flags. There are two types of invalid floating numbers: a NaN (not-a-number) and infinite.

In ISO C99 and POSIX 2001 you can use `isfinite(fval)` which returns a nonzero value if the value `fval` is not NaN or infinite.

You can also use `isnan(fval)` or `isinf(fval)` if you need more granularity.

Comment: +∞ and −∞ are not invalid floating-point values. They participate in operations in defined ways.